# Proof that $x \ dy \wedge dz$ is NOT exact on any open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Consider the smooth differential 2-form $\omega = x \ dy \wedge dz$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ (using the coordinates $(x,y,z)$ of course).

I'm trying to show that $\omega$ is NOT exact on any open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Suppose that $\omega$ is exact on some open subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{3}$. By definition, then there must exist a smooth differential $1$-form $\eta$ such that $d \eta = \omega$.

Since $\eta$ is a smooth differential 1-form, there exist functions $f,g,h \in C^{\infty}(A)$ such that:

$\eta = f \ dx + g \ dy + h \ dz$

Taking the differential of $\eta$, and computing a little, I find that:

$d \eta =  \left[ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right] dx \wedge dy + \left[ \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \right] dx \wedge dz + \left[ \frac{\partial h}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial g}{\partial z} \right] dy \wedge dz$

But since $d\eta = \omega$, this means that:

$\begin{cases} \ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0 \\
\ \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 0 \\
\ \frac{\partial h}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial g}{\partial z} = x
 \end{cases}$

....I get very stuck here. I am guessing there is some way to show that the above system of PDEs has no solution, and hence $\omega$ is NOT exact. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Exact forms are closed.

Comment: This form is not closed, $d(xdy\wedge dz)\not=0$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Thank you, this is so much simpler!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is very simple to answer; but just for interest here's how to make your approach work:

Differentiating the second equation by $y$ gives $h_{xy} = f_{zy}$, and the first by $z$ gives $g_{xz} = f_{zy}$. Thus we have $h_{xy} = g_{xz}$. But differentiate the third equation by $x$ and we get $h_{xy} = g_{xz} + 1$, a contradiction.